# Assembly x86 return after jump

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following code:

```
        input1:
            lea eax, module1
            push eax
            lea eax, format
            push eax
            call scanf
            add esp, 8

            call check1
            ret

        check1:
            mov eax, module1
            cmp eax, 0
            jl print
            jl input1

            cmp eax, 100
            jl print
            jg input1

            mov eax, inputnumber
            inc eax
            mov inputnumber, eax
            ret
```

I am trying to input some numbers and then check if the number is between 0 and 100. After I call input1 then it calls check1 to check if the number is in the range. In check1 if I jump to print how can I return back so I can continue the code and jmp to input1 ?

Comment: For future reference, assembly isn't just "assembly" - its architecture specific and you really should indicate which one. Since that looks like x86 assembly, most people who are familiar with ASMs will probably recognise it but they shouldn't need to work it out.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to include it. Included now.

Comment: You shouldn't jump between functions. Your `check` should probably return an error flag that you can then use to jump in your `input1`. Can you write this in C, for example?

Comment: I have to write it in assembly specifically. That is the main requirement. It is not necessary to be with functions. That is how i started it but I might change it just to jumps without any calls.

Comment: I meant, are you able to write this in C, as a way to see the structure.

Comment: I did write it in C with a few if statements and while loop. Now I just have hard time making it in assembly.

Comment: `jmp` doesn't save any return info, so the only way back is to hard-code `jmp a_label_in_check1` into `print` (and put that label where you want it in `check1`).  Like Jester said, it looks like you should write `input1` to loop if a check doesn't succeed.  Too much jumping around between blocks risks can get confusing (spaghetti code).

Comment: Since you wrote it in C, you can model your assembly code after the C code. That is, define the same functions and use the same control flow within each function. In C, you cannot jump between functions; in assembly, you also don’t want to do that.